# add hyperlink in notification of MVC Kendo UI

Tags: model-view-controller, kendo-ui, notifications, telerik, actionlink

I am trying to show some action link with the **notication** message of **Kendo UI MVC**. How to add action-link (**hyperlink**) with notification message.

Comment: Please show what you have tried so far, what result you expected and where it failed. You might also want to read https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example and https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.

Comment: You need help with the hyperlink, notification or both? Is this a kendo grid and you want the link on a row? Need much more info...

Comment: Its not a grid. When a pages loads we have to show some pending task or alerts as notification.In the notification we need to show the hyperlink to the task completion page.

Comment: Where does Kendo come in? Show some code.